# AnyLogic: Bug in illustrating Escalator Group in 3D view when applying certain size for escalator

Tags: anylogic

When using an escalator group, if I reduce its size, the lower landing is not depicted correctly in 3D view. But in 2D, it is illustrated exactly as I have designed. Below is an example, and images of produced escalator in 2D and 3D view is followed:

1-size of escalator group

[image: size of escalator group]

2-escalator group in AnyLogic graphical editor
[image: escalator group in AnyLogic graphical editor]

3-What is produced in 3D view
[image: What is produced in 3D view]

4-What is produced in 2D view
[image: What is produced in 2D view]

It is obvious that in 3D view upper landing length is depicted correctly, however, the lower landing is illustrated much longer than what should it be. Is there any way to solve it?

P.S. : In some other sizes which I tested, the lower landing was depicted wrong in 3D view again (longer or shorter than what it should be), contrary to its upper counterpart.Thus it seems this not a unique size problem.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, I have never really used these but could it be that the slope is hard-coded in 3D and hence your length determines the extra bit at the start? Or can you maybe set the slope to adjust properly?

Comment: I replicated your measurements and I get a beautiful escalator with everything perfectly in place. This means that your problem is not reproducible with the information provided.... I wouldn't discard that you made a mistake somewhere else... Can you try to replicate your problem having in the model nothing but an escalator?

Comment: Thank you Benjamin and Felipe. I did both things you've mentioned. Neither a new model containing nothing but the escalator, nor playing with the slope didn't solve the problem. And generally speaking, in my models it seems that the length of lower landing doesn't change AT ALL. And to @Felipe, when you change your lower landing length does it change in  3D view?

Comment: Yes everything changes equally in 2D and 3D. I dont see a problem. Using anylogic 8.3.3

Comment: I viewed 8.3.3 change history and this was part of it: Fixed bug: Escalator lower landing length set incorrectly in 3D. I use 8.3.2.

Comment: There you go. Update yourself

Comment: one of my favorite reads: AnyLogic update notes. Hidden gems more often than not :D